# ASP.NET Core Razor Page Logout Redirect Issue: White Screen on SignOut

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application with Razor Pages, and I've implemented registration and login features. However, I'm facing a problem with the logout functionality. When a user clicks on the logout button, the user is supposed to be redirected to a specific page, but instead, I'm encountering a white screen issue.

The current behavior is as follows: after clicking the logout button, the browser is redirected to "https://localhost:7082/signout-oidc?state=longstring", where I am greeted with a white screen. My expectation is to redirect the user to the home page or a specified page after logging out.

Here is the relevant code:

Logout button in Razor Page:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("SignOut", "Account", new { Area = "MicrosoftIdentity" })' class="logout-button">Logout</a>
```

SignOut action in the Account controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SignOut()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}
```

I suspect the issue might be related to the way the sign-out process is being handled or maybe the redirection after the sign-out is not correctly configured. The redirect for sign-out is set to "https://localhost:7082/signout-oidc", but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what I might be doing wrong? How can I ensure that after the sign-out process, the user is redirected to a designated page (like the home page) instead of being left on a white screen?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you redirected your user to the Login page `RedirectToPage("/Login")`;

Comment: Start from the start: 1. What does the URL in your HTML actually *LOOK* like for the logout href? Not in the razor page, but what URL gets generated/rendered. 2. If that URL looks good, then paste that URL in your browser and check if the route actually works. Debug your code and put a breakpoint in your controller to see if it's getting hit. 3 if the route doesn't work, then you need to fix the route. I don't know if the "RouteDebugger" nuget package works in asp.net core, but that's my go-to when routing doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, IceCode, I'll think about that. 
LarryBud: The href only generates the link "https://localhost:7082/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut"
after clicking on the account I want to log out, I get the following link: 
https://tenantname.ciamlogin.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7082%2Fsignout-oidc&state=verylongstring&x-client-SKU=ID_NET6_0&x-client-ver=6.33.0.0
after logging out, I get this link with the white blank space: https://localhost:7082/signout-oidc?state=longstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this service configure in my Program.cs.
I deleted this codeblock and it works fine now.

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
options => {
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Ausloggen";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify signout property in singoutasync method.

```
        public async Task SignOut()
        {
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = "/Index"
            };
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, props);
        }
```

You could also set a global redirect url in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {               
                    options.Events.OnSigningOut = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Index");                                
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Comment: I tried both options, both produced the same result: the white screen again.

Comment: `builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Logout";
    });`
I tried this part, it seems like the website ignores this.

Comment: @FabianH. What is the white screen url in the browser?

Comment: I had too much code in my Program.cs, I don't know why, but it works now. 
I deleted: builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
options => {
    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Ausloggen";
});